# Получение данных при связи Многие ко многим

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Есть 2 модели. Между ними связь многие ко многим. Вот они:

```
public class Orders
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public double TotalPrice { get; set; }

        public int ClientsId { get; set; }
        public virtual Clients Clients { get; set; }

        public int? WorkingId { get; set; }
        public virtual Working Working { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Spares> Spares { get; set; }

        public Orders()
        {
            Spares = new List<Spares>();
        }
    }

public class Spares
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string SparePartName { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
        public string WinCode { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Orders> Orders { get; set; }

        public Spares()
        {
            Orders = new List<Orders>();
        }
    }
```

Мне нужно достать все Spares, у котрых входит в коллекцию конкретный Order который я задаю.
Я попробовал вот как:

```
var tmp = db.Spares.Include(s => s.Orders.Where(o => o.Id == order.Id));
```

order.Id это мой order который у меня получен ранее в коде.

Но при такой попытке у меня выскочила ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так? Как можно вытащить необходимые мне данные?

Comment: @AK да, инклюд оказался не нужен. Большое спасибо. Помогло. Уже час наверное бился как это сделать)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то вы хотите

```
var tmp = db.Spares.Where(s => s.Orders.Any(o => o.Id == 123));
```

С Include (если вдруг вам нужен) то это будет

```
var tmp = db.Spares.Include(x => x.Orders).Where(s => s.Orders.Any(o => o.Id == 123));
```

Но похоже, что вам Include особо не нужен, просто вы не так поняли, для чего он применяется.